# Compile Error len is not yet stable as a const fn

Tags: rust

I get an error from one of my dependencies [`bytes`](https://crates.io/crates/bytes) `0.5.2`. Here a code example of the error:

```rust
pub const fn foo(foo: &'static [u8]) -> usize {
    foo.len()
}
```

```
error: `core::slice::<impl [T]>::len` is not yet stable as a const fn
 --> <source>:2:5
  |
2 |     foo.len()
  |     ^^^^^^^^^
error: aborting due to previous error
```

```
active toolchain
----------------

stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc (default) rustc 1.38.0 (625451e37 2019-09-23)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `0.5.x` would appear to require Rust 1.39 so the easiest option would likely be upgrading to the newest version.

The error states

> `core::slice::<impl [T]>::len` is not yet stable as a const fn

and if you look at [the release notes for `1.39`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-1390-2019-11-07) you can see that one of the entries is

> `str::len`, `[T]::len` and `str::as_bytes` are now const functions

so this crate specifically requires >=1.39

Comment: i run rustup update stable,it solved!thanks you very much!